# pymc random seed doesn't guarantee the same posterior samples?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings, pymc

If pymc.numpy.random.seed(0) guarantee the same random number sequence to initialize a stochastic variable (say a Uniform distribution), why does its posterior samples (from trace plot) don't have the same values for multiple runs with the same seed=0 ?

Is there any internal random seed encoded in the pymc module ? Or, this is cause by the  assigned "probability α" ? ( See  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm#Intuition  )

Have anyone encountered this problem ? Is this related to the older version of pymc that I'm using ? Currently, I'm using pymc version 2.2 because failed to install version 3 to my computer with windows 7 platform.

Comment: Are you sure you're reseting the seed *every time* you run the sampler?

Comment: @juliohm, I'm not sure of what you meant by re-setting the seed. The see is always set to 0 for every new run.

Comment: Ok, just to be sure you know the seed must be reset for results to be reproducible.

Comment: @juliohm, Have you encountered cases like mine problem? I mean have you check the trace plots if they are the same in several different runs but with same seed ?

Comment: I started using PyMC in a project, and then switched gears to another package. I had no opportunity to check reproducibility issues at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related to the old version you are using.  Setting the numpy random seed should make the PyMC computations reproducible. In my [simple example notebook here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/aflaxman/e0d61076595251e26199), this is the case.

I used PyMC 2.3.2 to check this, so it could be that upgrading your version to 2.3 will sort things out. If you upgrade and still get different results, then I think you have discovered a bug, and the PyMC developers would probably appreciate you filing an issue with a minimal example of how to reproduce it in [their github repository](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/issues?state=open).